# Can a static magnetic field passes through an electric charged surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits

I have two questions the first (look at Fig1) : I have a static magnetic field perpendicular to a charge surface, where the charges are moving in (let's say) the y-direction and the magnetic field in the z-direction, after some time where the hall field took place and the current flow got back to its initial state.
Can the magnetic fiel passes through the plate (we assume that the charged surface is much bigger than the surface on which the magnetic field is acting)[image: Fig1 : The current trajectory correct by Hall field]

The second question (Fig2) : I have now a coil with an alternating current inside, placed under a static magnetic fiel, the question is, will the magnetic field go through the coil ? and if it will, will it be changed?

[image: A circular coil with an alternating current (high frequency 5 MHz) running in it]

Thank you in advance for your answers